# What is the collective word in English for items that are compared with each other?

Tags: nouns

If I am comparing two or more items of certain brands, then by what single word collectively those items can be described?

I want to name the items to be compared. For example, "contestants" is the word for people who are competing with each other. So what will be the word for items/articles or things that are being compared?

Comment: You don't like *comparands* for some reason?  I think that word is found in mathematical contexts.

Comment: Yeah, they are *comparands*.  I can't understand why a lot of dictionaries don't appear to have this term, as it's commonly used in math and computer science.

Answer (score 2):

Comparables. This a word frequently used in real estate when comparing properties to each other or to a subject property, as a substitute for "comparable properties."

Example: Can you get me a list of comparables active on the market?
The comparables each have 4 bedrooms, 4 baths and a two car garage, but number 4 on the list has a pool.

You could substitute real estate for shampoo, or whatever you may be comparing, for example: The comparables are all coconut-oil based, but only one is organic.

Answer (score 0):

Pick one  of  below  according to  your  case:

- compared, likened, matched, weighed, collated, paralleled, liken together
- Competitors, entrants, fighters, applicants, candidates, aspirants, contenders, postulants, expectants, challengers, contenders, pretenders, claimants, supplicants, petitioners, suppliants, prayers, suitors